# Run Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana with 'docker-compose' command

Tags: elasticsearch, docker, logstash, docker-compose, kibana

I am going to run ELK with `docker-compose` command with the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
---
version: '2'
services:
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 5601:5601

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash
    links:
      - elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 5044:5044

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch
    cap_add:
      - IPC_LOCK
    volumes:
      - esdata1:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200

volumes:
  esdata1:
    driver: local
```

But I have few questions:

1) I specified `links` parameter to link containers but should I also specify `networks` parameter? What is it used for?

2) How can I change default users names and passwords for Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana?

3) Elasticsearch configuration parameters are stored in `elasticsearch.yml` file but where can I find that file? 
Is it possible to define Elasticsearch parameters such as `path.data`, `path.logs`, `cluster.name`, `node.name` directly in `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: They wont conplete answer but you can check that repository https://github.com/hkulekci/es5-devnot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)**
 The *links* parameter allows to access the linked container by its service name or alias. This will be possible for any docker network that both services have joined.

If you do not specify any networks under the service's *networks* key the services will join the docker default network (bridge I think).

You only have to specify a network name if you want your services to join a (number of) specific docker networks. Those again you can then either define under the top-level *networks* key (which lets docker-compose create the networks) or prepare outside of docker compose per `docker network create`

**2)** The images you are using are built with X-Pack, how to change the passwords is described here [X-Pack security](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/5.3/security-getting-started.html) Example taken from the documentation:

```
curl -XPUT -u elastic 'localhost:9200/_xpack/security/user/elastic/_password' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "password" : "elasticpassword"
}'

curl -XPUT -u elastic 'localhost:9200/_xpack/security/user/kibana/_password' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "password" : "kibanapassword"
}'

curl -XPUT -u elastic 'localhost:9200/_xpack/security/user/logstash_system/_password' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "password" : "logstashpassword"
}'
```

If you do not want to do that as a manual post setup step, you would have to create your own derived docker images.

**3)** The configuration parameters you would otherwise configure using the *elasticsearch.yml* may be set using environment variables as described by the [Elastic search docker documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html). Example taken from the documentation:

```
...
services:
  elasticsearch1:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.3.0
    container_name: elasticsearch1
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-cluster
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
...
```

Comment: Btw. I just found the time and mood to actually try that setup. I had to specify the image versions _5.3.0_ to be able to pull the images. Also I had to set the max virtual memory on my machine to satisfy the elasticsearch service. `sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144`. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Were you able to reach Kibana interface at `http://localhost:5601/` when you started all 3 apps?
I am using the same docker-compose.yml file but I am not able to reach Kibana. I am getting the following errors:
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-04-08T20:05:12Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":7,"message":"No living connections"}
kibana_1         | {"type":"log","@timestamp":"2017-04-08T20:05:12Z","tags":["warning","elasticsearch","admin"],"pid":7,"message":"Unable to revive connection: http://elasticsearch:9200/"}

Comment: This is from Elasticsearch log: [2017-04-08T20:05:27,517][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [hJd3Yol] started
[2017-04-08T20:05:39,047][ERROR][o.e.x.m.c.i.IndicesStatsCollector] [hJd3Yol] collector [indices-stats-collector] failed to collect data
org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlockException: blocked by: [SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE/1/state not recovered / initialized];
 at org.elasticsearch.cluster.block.ClusterBlocks.globalBlockedException(ClusterBlocks.java:165) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]

Comment: Yes, I was able to do that. 

But I had to make two corrections in your compose file: 1st, added the image versions, e.g. `docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.3.0` (thankfully it's the same version for all three). 2nd You named both the _kibana_ and the _logstash_ service "kibana", so I changed the _logstash_ service name to "logstash".

 And then I had to make the virtual memory setting I mentioned above. But your elasticsearch service seems to run from the logs you posted, so that is probably not an issue (anymore) for you.

Comment: It happened when I changed passwords for all three apps according to documentation notes here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/5.3/security-getting-started.html After I changed passwords back to default `changeme`, everything started working good. Do you know why that happened?

Comment: Well, now I know what happened... The passwords are changed in the elasticSearch service. If the password of the kibana user is changed, which is done with the `curl` statement, then the kibana service's configuration (kibana.yml or environment variables) has to be changed. See here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html
So after changing the password you would have to stop the kibana service, update the compose file adding the environment variable and then restart the kibana service.